# What is the term (phrase) for the ability to move a disk from one PC to another

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

Context: two Dell desktop PCs of the **same model** are in two different physical locations.  There is a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/374171/using-one-hard-drive-with-one-os-on-two-computers) with a different context: the PCs are **not the same model**.

The goal is to configure a single windows 7 SSD so that it can be shuttled back and forth between the two locations and used in either desktop.  The problem is that Microsoft software can detect that the drive has been moved to a new box and ask for reactivation.

**I have been able to move a Windows 10 disk  between the two similar Dell Desktops** (same model): this disk also works in a third Dell of a different model number.  Ubuntu also lends itself from easily moving between hardware.

What is the search term for this form of disk-portability between machines in a Windows context?   I ask because I would like to use the most common search terms in Google to learn how to outfit a Windows 7 disk for the two Dells.  Said Windows-10 disk was activated via digital entitlement.

Comment: Windows locks to specific devices in you system using serial numbers and hardware IDs. I do not believe what you are wanting has been possible since Windows XP

Comment: Windows-ToGo can be used for this but requires windows 8 or 10 and can only be used on a computer where Windows is already installed. Basically, you create a 2nd install with a portable drive and you boot from that drive into the existing windows install. when booted from a windows-togo install, the main drives are inaccessible and only your external drive is accessible. You can move this disk to other systems to have a portable install.

Comment: @Mokubai I think maybe Win XP was fine with it if the motherboards were the same / motherboard chipset was the same.   Win9X you could do it on any two different motherboards. I don't know about reactivation issue though.,  just mentioning the difference between 9X and XP(ot NT family)